# Modify function to use it in multiple triggers

Tags: postgresql, trigger, insert, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have tables that have almost the same columns. The first table has the current values and the other table has the old values and an additional column to store the date data is inserted. The second table is named as the first table with the prefix **_bit**. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  f1 integer NOT NULL,
  f2 character varying(10) NOT NULL,
  cuando timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);

CREATE TABLE _bitx (
  id integer,
  f1 integer,
  f2 character varying(10),
  cuando timestamp without time zone,
  cuandobit timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
);
```

I have a trigger function that copies the `OLD` values of a table to another:

```
CREATE FUNCTION bitacoratabla() RETURNS trigger AS $$
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO _bitx VALUES((OLD).*);
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigbitx
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON public.x
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.bitacoratabla();
```

**All this works fine but I must do this for multiple tables that follow the same rules.**

I modified the function in order to create the name of the table where I will insert data but I am having problems with that and with **(OLD).***

```
CREATE FUNCTION bitacoratabla() RETURNS trigger AS $$
   DECLARE
      tabla text := '_bit' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME);

   BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || tabla || ' VALUES(' || (OLD).* || ')';
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I am new to PL/pgSQL and thought I did not have to do more. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

As all you suggest it is better to use `format()` and pass values with `USING` keyword. **Thank you**. This is what I did:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bitacoratabla() RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $$
   BEGIN
      EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I SELECT $1.*', '_bit' || TG_TABLE_NAME) USING OLD;
      RETURN NEW;
   END 
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: Reference answer with detailed explanation on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7915100/939860

Comment: Are you aware that it's ok (even encouraged) to answer your own question?

Comment: As everybody has added something useful I think it is not fair to answer my own question using that info. I was waiting for an answer like yours, that clearly explain why is better to do it this way. What should I do in these cases?

Comment: Hard to say. Maybe clarify your question that your interested in the *Why* specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers so far still suffer from one or the other shortcoming.

1. Use the `USING` clause of `EXECUTE` to pass *values*. Do *not* concatenate the text representation of values into the SQL string. Expensive and error-prone.
2. Properly escape *all* identifiers when used in dynamic SQL to defend against sneaky errors with double quoted identifiers and possible SQL injection. Even if you think you do not need it. Do it on principal.

   But *this* would be an error waiting to happen:

   <strike>`'_bit' || quote_ident(TG_TABLE_NAME)`</strike>

   For a table name `"MyTable"` this would produce `_bit"MyTable"` - syntactical nonsense. It must be:

   ```
   quote_ident('_bit' || TG_TABLE_NAME)
   ```

   Or use `format('... %I ...', '_bit' || TG_TABLE_NAME)`

The only correct solution is what you added to your question yourself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bitacoratabla()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I SELECT $1.*', '_bit' || TG_TABLE_NAME)
   USING OLD;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Detailed explanation:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)

#### But why does it work with an additional column?

> the other table has the old values and an additional column to store the date data

This *happens* to work as long as the additional column in the target table comes last because, [quoting the manual on `INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#AEN88417):

> If no list of column names is given at all, the default is all the
>   columns of the table in their declared order; or the first ***N*** column
>   names, if there are only ***N*** columns supplied by the `VALUES` clause or ***query***.

So you better be sure the additional column(s) come last in the table definition of the target table, and all other columns are listed in matching order, now and in all future - or you must add an explicit target column list (which would prevent a generic function to begin with).